# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:

Tags: java

tengo un problema con un método para consumir un servicio con el método POST, el cual lo realizo por Spring Boot. bueno resulta que me aparece el error 400, se que hace referencia a la Url lo que sucede es que la url es bien ya la he probado con postman y funciona sigo sin entender que puedo estar haciendo mal aquí dejo el método para ver si alguien puede ayudarme, gracias.

public StringBuilder datosVehiculo(String placa) {

```
     String valor = this.token().replaceAll("\"", "");

      
     try {
      
     URL url = new URL("https://api.datatools.com.co:8085/api/circulemos/vehiculos/25175000/ComercialAPI/api/Consulta/consultarVehiculo/V1"); 
     
     String dato = "placa=SKI918";
     
     HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     con.setDoOutput(true); 
     con.setDoInput(true); 
     con.setRequestMethod("POST");
     con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
     con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
     con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " +valor);
     
     
     // Obtenemos el OutputStream para agregar el json de la petición.
     OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream(); 
     byte[] input = dato.getBytes("utf-8"); 
     os.write(input, 0, input.length);
     
     // Obtener la respuesta BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8")); 
         StringBuilder respuesta = new StringBuilder();
         String acumuladorRespuesta = null;
         while ((acumuladorRespuesta = br.readLine()) != null) {
             respuesta.append(acumuladorRespuesta.trim());
         }
     
     System.out.println(respuesta.toString());
     
     
     
     
     }catch (IOException e) { 
         e.getMessage(); 
         e.printStackTrace(); } catch
     (Exception e) { 
             e.getMessage(); 
             e.printStackTrace(); 
             }
     
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Por qué no usas un restTemplate en vez de hacerlo con el HttpURLConnection? Hace que sea mucho más fácil tanto enviar como recibir datos, pudiendo usar los objetos directamente en vez de tener que leer los stream y parsear tú todo.

Comment: bueno voy a intentarlo de esa forma muchas gracias.